# Drawing on canvas not working on sensors(phones) HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I made canvas that you can draw on it, but when I resize website to mobile size it doesn't work. My code only works on mouse. Is there any way to make it also work on mobile devices. Here's my code:

```
const points = [];
const mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, button: false }
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvents);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvents);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseEvents);
var x = "black",
    y = 2;
function mouseEvents(e) {
    mouse.x = e.pageX - 1;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - 1;
    const lb = mouse.button;
    mouse.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
    if (mouse.button) {
        if (!lb) { points.length = 0 }
            points.push({ x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y });
            drawPoints();
    }
}

function drawPoints() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.beginPath();
    if (mode == "pen") {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        for (const p of points) { ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y); }
        ctx.stroke();
    } else {
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"mousemove"` by `"pointermove"` and so on to cover both mouse and touch input. For the event mentioned above, you might have to call `e.StopPropagation()` additionally to prevent page scrolling on mobile devices.